# Fetch data from MySQL DB with Drupal for AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, drupal-7

Good evening!
I have a problem with fetching data from DB.
There are the project Drupal+AngularJS.
Without the Drupal I was able to get the data from MySQL with PHP for Angular:
in the file **index.php**:
`...

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("usercontroller", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.displayData = function () {
            $http.get("select.php")
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.names = data;
                });
        }
    });`
```

and in the file **select.php**:

```
<?php
//select.php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "testing");
$output = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}


?>
```

But, how can I do it WITH Drupal? How can I create the page like select.php?
I don't understand, help me please ))

Thank you all!

Comment: I tried to add a page following the example [page-programatically](http://befused.com/drupal/page-programatically) but it's no worked<br> GET http://testmapapi.hm:8888/select.tpl.php 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/services, also check about the Drupal headless

Answer (score 0):

Create and expose service from Drupal .

1. Use services module to create and expose a service
2. if data is to extracted from a standard drupal entity - use views and then expose its output as a service.

Swapnil S